# RavenDB - prevent exception on query error

Tags: ravendb

I am attempting to implement some customized searching in an application that allows a user to type in certain fields and terms and query for a result; So for instance, there is a text box and they can type... `Name: Stacey` and it runs some code.

That works fine, if they give it a valid name. But if they give it information it can't find, I get an exception and I can't figure out how to stop it. A `try` doesn't seem to work, either; The code isn't too complex, but it is a bit broken up.

Basically, this runs after receiving zero or two strings from a controller method. The first string is the field, and the second is the value to query for. If I give it valid input, it works fine; But anything else causes the program to crash. Is there anything I can do about this?

The long-winded callback process is because each controller method needs to react differently to the results, but that's not related to this problem.

```
    private JsonResult JsonDataFromDataSourceRequest<T, TIndexCreator>
        ([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,
        Func<IDocumentQuery<T>, string, string, IDocumentQuery<T>> search,
        Func<IDocumentQuery<T>, IDocumentQuery<T>> sort)
        where T : IHasName
        where TIndexCreator : Raven.Client.Indexes.AbstractIndexCreationTask, new() {
        RavenQueryStatistics statistics;

        var query = RavenSession
            .Advanced.DocumentQuery<T, TIndexCreator>()
            .WhereEquals("collection", typeof(T).RavenCollection())
            .WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow()
            .Statistics(out statistics); // output our query statistics

        // we can accept a sorting system, or additional query options here
        if (sort != null)
            query = sort(query);

        if (request.Filters != null) {
            if (request.Filters.Any()) {
                var filters = request.Filters.ToFilters();

                // determine the field/term to search by
                var name = filters.Count > 0 ? filters[0].Value.ToString() : null;
                var field = filters.Count > 0 ? filters[0].Member.ToString() : "Name";

                if (name != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) {
                    query = query.AndAlso().Search(field, name);
                }
            }
        }

        var results = query
            .OrderBy(n => n.Name)
            .Skip((request.Page - 1) * request.PageSize)
            .Take(request.PageSize)
            .ToList();

        var totalResults = statistics.TotalResults;

        return Json(new { data = results, total = totalResults });
    }
```

## Update

### `System.InvalidOperationException`

The exception thrown is `System.InvalidOperationException`. When I drill down on the debugger, the actual query sent to Raven is in the form of;

`{collection:users AND DisplayName: ( Stacey)}`

It's kind of a mixed bag; Let me explain a few things.

`collection` exists because this index is used for a lot of different objects, but many, if not all of them, share several similar fields. It seemed simpler to just make the collection a part of the query than try to find a way to use the `Type` in the `Query<T>` call.

#### Is it possible to keep the flexibility and give the query a specific `TModel` to query against? I wanted to avoid making dozens of repetitive indexes.

This does appear to happen when the user tries to lookup a field that is *not on the type of object being examined*.

**In other words**, even though `Owner` is indexed, if the user types `Owner: Ciel` against a page that looks up `Users`, which **do not** have the `Owner` field (but many, many other classes do), it throws this error. It does this if they try to type in a field that is not indexed as well.

#### Is it possible to return *nothing* if the query fails?

Here is a look at the index I am using. Perhaps there is a simpler way to do this without the `collection` field, but I'm not aware of it off the top of my head (but I'm still inexperienced). *There are almost 28 different pages, each with search functionality. There are so many similar fields between some of the entities that it seemed pointless to make 28 different indexes.*

```
public class EntityByName : AbstractIndexCreationTask {
    public override IndexDefinition CreateIndexDefinition() {
        return new IndexDefinition {
            Map = @"
                from doc in docs 
                let collection = doc[""@metadata""][""Raven-Entity-Name""] 
                select new { 
                    doc.Id, 
                    doc.Name, 
                    doc.Owner,  
                    doc.Group,
                    doc.Email,
                    Tags = doc.Tags.Select( r => r.Name ),
                    collection 
                };",
            Indexes ={
                {"Id", FieldIndexing.Analyzed},
                {"Name", FieldIndexing.Analyzed},
                {"Owner", FieldIndexing.Analyzed},
                {"Tags", FieldIndexing.Analyzed},
                {"Group", FieldIndexing.Analyzed},
                {"Email", FieldIndexing.Analyzed}
            }
        };
    }

    public override string IndexName {
        get { return "Raven/DocumentsByEntity"; }
    }
}
```

### Exception Message

Here is a full exception message.

```
Url: "/databases/dev-isolated/indexes/Raven/DocumentsByEntity?&query=collection%3Ausers%20AND%20Number%3A%28%203%29&pageSize=5&sort=Name&SortHint-collection=String&SortHint-Name=String&cutOff=2015-10-02T15%3A12%3A31.5784892Z&waitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow=true"

System.ArgumentException: The field 'DisplayName' is not indexed, cannot query on fields that are not indexed
   at Raven.Database.Indexing.Index.AssertQueryDoesNotContainFieldsThatAreNotIndexed(IndexQuery indexQuery, AbstractViewGenerator viewGenerator) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Database\Indexing\Index.cs:line 1130
   at Raven.Database.Indexing.Index.IndexQueryOperation.<Query>d__5a.MoveNext() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Database\Indexing\Index.cs:line 1252
   at Raven.Database.Util.ActiveEnumerable`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 enumerable) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Database\Util\ActiveEnumerable.cs:line 16
   at Raven.Database.Actions.QueryActions.DatabaseQueryOperation.Init() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Database\Actions\QueryActions.cs:line 245
   at Raven.Database.Actions.QueryActions.<>c__DisplayClasse.<Query>b__a(IStorageActionsAccessor accessor) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Database\Actions\QueryActions.cs:line 118
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.ExecuteBatch(Action`1 action, EsentTransactionContext transactionContext) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Database\Storage\Esent\TransactionalStorage.cs:line 843
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Batch(Action`1 action) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Database\Storage\Esent\TransactionalStorage.cs:line 807
   at Raven.Database.Actions.QueryActions.Query(String index, IndexQuery query, CancellationToken externalCancellationToken) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Database\Actions\QueryActions.cs:line 108
   at Raven.Database.Server.Controllers.IndexController.PerformQueryAgainstExistingIndex(String index, IndexQuery indexQuery, Etag& indexEtag, HttpResponseMessage msg, CancellationToken token) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Database\Server\Controllers\IndexController.cs:line 625
   at Raven.Database.Server.Controllers.IndexController.ExecuteQuery(String index, Etag& indexEtag, HttpResponseMessage msg, CancellationToken token) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Database\Server\Controllers\IndexController.cs:line 570
   at Raven.Database.Server.Controllers.IndexController.GetIndexQueryResult(String index, CancellationToken token) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Database\Server\Controllers\IndexController.cs:line 541
   at Raven.Database.Server.Controllers.IndexController.IndexGet(String id) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Database\Server\Controllers\IndexController.cs:line 182
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
```

## Fix

I have made the appropriate changes, this is the final result of the method;

```
    private JsonResult JsonDataFromDataSourceRequest<T, TIndexCreator>
        ([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,
        Func<IDocumentQuery<T>, string, string, IDocumentQuery<T>> search,
        Func<IDocumentQuery<T>, IDocumentQuery<T>> sort)
        where T : IHasName
        where TIndexCreator : Raven.Client.Indexes.AbstractIndexCreationTask, new() {

        try {

            // we need to be able to catch some query statistics to make sure that the
            // grid view is complete and accurate, with paging
            RavenQueryStatistics statistics;

            // try to query the items listing as quickly as we can, getting only the
            // page we want out of it
            var query = RavenSession
                .Advanced.DocumentQuery<T, TIndexCreator>()
                .WhereEquals("collection", typeof(T).RavenCollection())
                .WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow()
                .Statistics(out statistics); // output our query statistics

            // we can accept a sorting system, or additional query options here
            if (sort != null)
                query = sort(query);

            // deserialize the contents of the kendo grid filter
            if (request.Filters != null) {
                if (request.Filters.Any()) {
                    var filters = request.Filters.ToFilters();

                    var name = filters.Count > 0 ? filters[0].Value.ToString() : null;
                    var field = filters.Count > 0 ? filters[0].Member.ToString() : "Name";

                    if (name != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) {
                        query = search(query, field, name);
                    }
                }
            }

            // finish constructing the items query
            var results = query
                .OrderBy(n => n.Name)
                .Skip((request.Page - 1) * request.PageSize)
                .Take(request.PageSize)
                .ToList();

            var totalResults = statistics.TotalResults;

            return Json(new { data = results, total = totalResults, errors = "" });
        }
        catch {

            // the user tried to ask for something
            // that doesn't exist, or a field that
            // cannot be queried
            var results = new List<T>();

            // total results is always 0 on an error
            var totalResults = 0;

            var errors = new List<string> {
                "You have attempted to query an invalid field, or given an inappropriate value."
            };

            return Json(new { data = results, total = totalResults, errors = errors });
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the actual exception trown?

Comment: Okay, I have updated the question with much more information, including more detailed explanations, the index being used, and the exception

Comment: Sorry, to also answer you directly, the exception is `System.InvalidOperationException`

Comment: after trying a few more things, wrapping the WHOLE thing in a big ugly `try/catch` block does seem to stop the problem but... something tells me that's not a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty clear:

```
The field 'DisplayName' is not indexed, cannot query on fields that are not indexed
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess what confused me is that I figured trying to query something that didn't work would just return 0 results, so the behavior was a bit disarming. As I asked on the RavenDB forums, is there any inherit problem with letting a `try/catch` behavior capture this and return the error more gracefully to the user?